# Require HTML5 to use a website

Tags: html, required

Theoretically, could you detect if a browser supports HTML5 and prompt the visitor to upgrade to IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera if it doesn't support some features like CSS3 or audio/video tags?

I'm developing a hobby music site in a mostly walled-garden and would like to prevent people with anitquated browsers from accessing/logging into the site.

Mass appeal is not a requirement as the site is for a niche and maximizes JavaScript and HTML5 use.

Comment: @Andy Since no browser will ever fully support the HTML5 standard, I recommend just putting the site offline `:)`

Comment: I didn't ask for full HTML 5 support, but since the site focuses on music (personal hobby site) and I'd rather have it be more on the bleeding edge, I don't mind keeping people out of the garden.

Comment: @Andy Then what do you mean by "if a browser supports HTML5" if not fully? What features to  you mean then? HTML5 introduces hundreds of new features? You have to be specific.

Comment: @Andy [Y U NO](http://images1.memegenerator.net/ImageMacro/6648580/HTML5-IS-AN-UMBRELLA-TERM-FOR-THOUSANDS-OF-NEW-FEATURES-Y-U-NO-UNDERSTAND.jpg?imageSize=Medium&generatorName=Y-U-NO) `:)`

Comment: Specifically, audio, maybe video. Sacrificing audience to do away with plugins like Flash on this project is fine with me. Its mostly a hobby site of mine that I mainly use to build my skills and try new things I don't get to implement in the projects I do at work.

Comment: Thanks for the overdone meme; my original question specifically mentioned audio/video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the modernizr javascript api to detect the HTML5 features you desire.

http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional comment to show a warning to IE non-browsers:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> Get out of here! <![endif]-->
```

(You can also include a `<script>` tag that redirects to an upgrade page)

Comment: That's kind of what I wanted, but more to detect all browsers instead of just IE.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *theoretically*, yes you could. However, it would really be a pain and not at all foolproof as it would likely rely upon javascript for implementation which could easily be circumvented.

Also, in practice, just about any user agent parameter can be spoofed, so you really couldn't rely upon user agent parameter detection to determine whether or not a user agent actually supports a specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/everything.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Modernizr looks like it could be a good slution, with a noscript fallback.

Answer (score 0):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) may be a good starting point for you, in the case of detecting HTML5 video.